# How do I attach crystals to a shaman stick without using adhesive?

Tags: adhesives

I'm making a shaman stick and I want to attach crystals to it but as it will be used in rituals, I don't want to use anything man-made like adhesive. Is there a way to attach them using something natural?

Comment: How big are the crystals? How natural do you require? I assume wire is out but something like beeswax would be permissible (though it's too soft). Are your crystals even natural?

Comment: Hi Stargazer, welcome to Arts & Crafts! How large and thick is the stick? How large are the crystals? There are many organic adhesives: is making your own adhesives out of natural components good enough?

Answer (score 2):

Adhesives based on [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(resin)) (e.g. resin from pine tree sap) and beeswax have been used for millenia.  This makes a hot-melting glue that's strong enough to secure knife handles.

One example is [Cutler's Resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutler%27s_resin). Here's [one of many recipes](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/paleoplanet69529/how-to-make-cutler-s-resin-t55490.html); other similar compounds include stone dust (e.g. ochre), and were [used in ancient Eqypt](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/4255/319) (an old answer of mine).  The effect of the beeswax is to soften the pitch, while stone dust (or presumably wood dust) is used as a filler.

I reckon you might want to slightly inlay the crystals to make them more secure